# Document class for various formats

Tags: c#, beginner

I must to model Document class. I receive document as bytes array.
I can receive pdf, zip, text and xml documents. After few operation I must store documents. If document is in xml format I can get some nodes or transform it by xlst and then store.How can I improve my code? Is it good idea to use here builder or factory method patterns?

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string document1 = "<document>Content</document>";
            byte[] document2 = new byte[] { 80, 65, 78, 75, 65, 74 };
            byte[] document3 = new byte[] { 8, 68, 78, 78, 60, 73 };

            var document1Binary = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(document1);
            var binaryDocumentDetails = new DocumentDetails(1, "DefaultXml.xml", DocFormat.Xml, DocType.External);
            var documentXml = new XmlDocument(document1Binary, binaryDocumentDetails, "Test.xml");

            var binaryDocumentDetails1 = new DocumentDetails(1, "DefaultBinary.bin", DocFormat.Bin, DocType.Inner);
            var binaryDocument1 = new BinaryDocument(document2, Encoding.UTF8, binaryDocumentDetails1, "Test.bin");

            var binaryDocumentDetails2 = new DocumentDetails(1, "DefaultPdf.pdf", DocFormat.Bin, DocType.Inner);
            var binaryDocument2 = new BinaryDocument(document2, Encoding.UTF8, binaryDocumentDetails2, "TestDocument.pdf");

            var documentRepository = new List<BinaryDocument>();
            documentRepository.Add(documentXml);
            documentRepository.Add(binaryDocument1);
            documentRepository.Add(binaryDocument2);
        }
    }

    public enum DocFormat { Bin, Xml }
    public enum DocType { Inner, External }
    public enum Compression { Gzip, Zip}

    public class DocumentDetails
    {
        public byte DocTypeId { get; set; }
        public string DefaultFileName { get; }
        public string FileExtension { get; set; }
        public DocFormat Format { get; set; }
        public DocType FormType { get; set; }
        public DocumentDetails(byte docTypeId, string defaultFileName, DocFormat format, DocType formType)
        {
            DocTypeId = docTypeId;
            DefaultFileName = defaultFileName;
            Format = format;
            FormType = formType;
        }
    }
    public abstract class Document
    {
        public byte[] Body { get; protected set; }
        public string FileName { get; private set; }
        public Encoding Encoding { get; protected set; }
        protected Document(byte[] body, string fileName, Encoding encoding)
        {
            Body = body;
            Encoding = encoding;
            FileName = fileName;
        }
        public void ChangeContent(Document sourceDocument)
        {
            Body = sourceDocument.Body;
            Encoding = sourceDocument.Encoding;
            FileName = sourceDocument.FileName;
        }
    }

    public class BinaryDocument : Document
    {
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public bool AllowOverwrite { get; set; }
        public Compression Compression { get; set; }
        public DocumentDetails DocumentDetails { get; set; }

        public BinaryDocument(byte[] content, DocumentDetails documentDetails, string fileName) : this(content, Encoding.UTF8, documentDetails, fileName)
        {

        }
        public BinaryDocument(byte[] content, Encoding encoding, DocumentDetails documentDetails, string fileName) : base(content, fileName, encoding)
        {
            IsActive = true;
            DocumentDetails = documentDetails;
        }
        protected BinaryDocument(BinaryDocument binaryDocument) : base(binaryDocument.Body, binaryDocument.FileName, binaryDocument.Encoding)
        {
            IsActive = binaryDocument.IsActive;
            AllowOverwrite = binaryDocument.AllowOverwrite;
            Compression = binaryDocument.Compression;
            DocumentDetails = binaryDocument.DocumentDetails;
        }

        public void UpdateCompression(Compression compression)
        {
            Compression = compression;
        }
        public void UpdateDocumentDetails(DocumentDetails documentDetails)
        {
            DocumentDetails = documentDetails;
        }

        public string GetContentAsString()
        {
            return Encoding.GetString(Body);
        }

        public void UpdateDocument(byte[] body, Encoding encoding)
        {
            Body = body;
            Encoding = encoding;
        }
    }

    public class XmlDocument : BinaryDocument
    {
        public XDocument LoadedXmlDocument { get; set; }

        public XmlDocument(byte[] content, DocumentDetails documentForm, string fileName) : base(content, documentForm, fileName)
        {
            LoadedXmlDocument = Load();
        }

        public XmlDocument(byte[] content, Encoding encoding, DocumentDetails documentForm, string fileName) : base(content, encoding, documentForm, fileName)
        {
            LoadedXmlDocument = Load();
        }

        public XmlDocument(BinaryDocument documentPart)
          : this(documentPart.Body, documentPart.Encoding, documentPart.DocumentDetails, documentPart.FileName)
        {
        }

        private XDocument Load()
        {
            XDocument loadedXml;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Body))
            {
                using (var xr = XmlReader.Create(ms))
                {
                    loadedXml = XDocument.Load(xr);
                }
            }
            return loadedXml;
        }

        public static bool TryParse(BinaryDocument documentPart)
        {
            bool result = true;

            var readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings
            {
                ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document,
                CheckCharacters = true,
                ValidationType = ValidationType.None
            };

            var stream = documentPart.GetContentAsString();
            try
            {
                using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, readerSettings))
                {
                    while (reader.Read()) { }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                result = false;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have other document types than `BinaryDocument` that derives from `Document`?

Comment: No, It's only BinaryDocument class

Comment: It's a good question, but I think, your use case is poor. You write, that you receive the data as byte arrays, but you show `document1` as a string. It's also unclear from where you have or how you determine the metadata for each document. Could you provide an example that is a little more like the actual use?